# rosjava: Couldn't find executable named run.py

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run a java program but I have this error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run.py below /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap

As I see I couldn't found run.py. But I just installed the rosjava from the repository for electric.

What can be happening? Where must be the run.py script?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11177/rosjava:-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-run.py/) by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosjava API is still in flux.  The run.py executable has not been released into the debian version; instead you have to install rosjava from source:

```
hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg rosjava_core
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2